# Magento import: Can not find required columns: sku

Tags: import, magento-1.9

I am going nuts here with Magento's import function. I have created one template product within my store and then exported it, so I can see what the attributes look like. Next I used Pentaho Data Integration to transform our suppliers product list into that format.

The header row contains, like the export, the service columns (starting with an underline). Here is one record of what my generated data looks like:

```
sku,_store,_attribute_set,_type,_category,_root_category,_product_websites,color,cost,country_of_manufacture,created_at,custom_design,custom_design_from,custom_design_to,custom_layout_update,description,gallery,gift_message_available,has_options,image,image_label,manufacturer,media_gallery,meta_description,meta_keyword,meta_title,minimal_price,msrp,msrp_display_actual_price_type,msrp_enabled,name,news_from_date,news_to_date,options_container,page_layout,price,required_options,short_description,small_image,small_image_label,special_from_date,special_price,special_to_date,status,tax_class_id,thumbnail,thumbnail_label,updated_at,url_key,url_path,visibility,weight,qty,min_qty,use_config_min_qty,is_qty_decimal,backorders,use_config_backorders,min_sale_qty,use_config_min_sale_qty,max_sale_qty,use_config_max_sale_qty,is_in_stock,notify_stock_qty,use_config_notify_stock_qty,manage_stock,use_config_manage_stock,stock_status_changed_auto,use_config_qty_increments,qty_increments,use_config_enable_qty_inc,enable_qty_increments,is_decimal_divided,_links_related_sku,_links_related_position,_links_crosssell_sku,_links_crosssell_position,_links_upsell_sku,_links_upsell_position,_associated_sku,_associated_default_qty,_associated_position,_tier_price_website,_tier_price_customer_group,_tier_price_qty,_tier_price_price,_group_price_website,_group_price_customer_group,_group_price_price,_media_attribute_id,_media_image,_media_lable,_media_position,_media_is_disabled
4053258104446,,Default,simple,"Schmuck/Halsschmuck",Default Category,base,,,,25.07.2015 20:06,,,,,"Collier, PVC, braun, 42 cm, Karabinerverschluss 925/- S, Durchmesser ca. 2 mm",,,0,"35416.jpg",,"JOBO",,,,,,,"Konfiguration verwenden","Konfiguration verwenden","Collier PVC braun, Verschluss aus 925 Silber 42 cm Karabiner                    ",,,"Artikelinformationsspalte",,5,0,"Collier PVC braun, Verschluss aus 925 Silber 42 cm Karabiner","no_selection",,,,,1,2,"no_selection",,2015/07/25 20:06:32.291,,,4,,,,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
```

Magento complains with:

```
Can not find required columns: sku
```

I just don't see what might be wrong with my data. Obviously the sku is there, and my DB is empty! Things I have checked:

- File-Encoding is UTF-8
- Tried with LR and CR/LF
- Strings are surrounded by "

Which fields are manadatory for an import? I just coudn't find anything within the documentation.

I have spent timeless hours on this. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Check if your column names are exactly the same as database names -

Moreover, encoding should be UTF-8 without BOM